# JSF + Hibernate : Insertar datos desde un archivo .txt a tabla de base de datos

Tags: java, mvc, poo, jsf, hibernate

Buen día;

Estoy manejando **Hibernate** Y **JSF**  mediante el estilo de arquitectura MVC en la creación de un proyecto, sin embargo, me genera la duda de como podría leer los datos que están dentro de un archivo txt que cargo mediante un `inputFile` y luego realizar la inserción de esos datos a una de las tablas de la base datos.

La información que esta contenida en el .txt es de la siguiente forma:

**dato1|dato2|dato3**

Esto correspondería a un solo registro en la base de datos. La idea es poder registrar usuarios por medio de este archivo txt, por lo que cada columna del archivo es un atributo de usuario.

Realice una clase controladora en la cual tengo un método para poder leer el archivo; me funciona perfectamente, ahora no se como realizar la inserción a la base de datos.

Esta es la clase:

```
public class CargarArchivoRequest {

    public CargarArchivoRequest() {
    }

    Part archivoCarga;

    public Part getArchivoCarga() {
        return archivoCarga;
    }

    public void setArchivoCarga(Part archivoCarga) {
        this.archivoCarga = archivoCarga;
    }

    public void ingresarDocumento(){

        try {
            InputStreamReader reader = new 
            InputStreamReader(this.archivoCarga.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine())!=null){
                System.out.println(line);
            }       

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias! Estaré atento a cualquier respuesta.

Comment: Creo ya lo llevas encaminado, tendria que tomar cada linea, hacer un split por separador correspondiente y crear tu objeto que vas a insertar en la base de datos

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta @juandej18. Llevo muy poco implementando **Hibernate** por lo que no se como hacer la inserción de los datos en este caso. Son datos básicos como nombre, email, direccion...